# modifying double pointer to an integer array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, double-pointer

I have a pointer to an `int *array`, I allocated it and then pass it to a function in order to fill in the elements of the array.

```
void function(int **arr);

int main()
{
    int *array;
    array=calloc(4, sizeof(int));
    function(&array);
    return0;
}


void function(int **arr)
{
    int *tmp;
    tmp=calloc(4, sizeof(int));
    tmp[0]=1;
    tmp[1]=2;
    tmp[2]=3;
    tmp[3]=4;
}
```

I want to assign `tmp` to `arr`. How can I do it?

Comment: `*arr = tmp;` doesn't work?

Comment: not at all. :( I should solve this problem ASAP, without changing the function prototype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to `calloc` `array` in `main`, first of all. It's a pointer and all you need to do is assign `tmp` to it. Here's how:

```
void function(int **arr);

int main()
{
    int *array;
    size_t i;

    function(&array);
    // do stuff with array
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }
    // then clean up
    free(array);

    return 0;
}


void function(int **arr)
{
    int *tmp;
    tmp=calloc(4, sizeof(int));
    tmp[0]=1;
    tmp[1]=2;
    tmp[2]=3;
    tmp[3]=4;

    *arr = tmp;
}
```

Comment: it still int the main function prints out 98712387 instead of 1,2,3,4.

Comment: @reshad How are you printing the array? Don't print the pointer, print the indeces.

Comment: I am printing with for(i=0; i<4; i++) printf("%d", array[i]);

Comment: THANKKKKSS A LOOOOOOT ! the problem was that I free tmp at the end of the function which was wrong !!!

Comment: @reshad but there was no free in your code in the question... Not fair to us :-)

Answer (score 4):

You should not do that because in this case there will be a memory leak because you already allocated memory for pointer array and the assignment will overwrite the value stored in the pointer. Write the function simpler

```
void function(int **arr)
{
    int *tmp = *arr;

    tmp[0]=1;
    tmp[1]=2;
    tmp[2]=3;
    tmp[3]=4;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void init( int **a, size_t n, int value )
{
    int *tmp = *a;
    size_t i = 0;

    for ( ; i < n; i++ ) tmp[i] = value++;
}

void display ( int *a, size_t n )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    for ( ; i < n; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    printf( "\n" );
}

int main(void)
{
    int *a;
    size_t n = 4;

    a = calloc( n, sizeof( int ) );

    init( &a, n, 0 );
    display( a, n );

    init( &a, n, 10 );
    display( a, n );

    free( a );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 
10 11 12 13
```

If you need to realloc the original array in a function then this can be done the followingway

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void init( int **a, size_t n, int value )
{
    int *tmp = *a;
    size_t i = 0;

    for ( ; i < n; i++ ) tmp[i] = value++;
}

void display ( int *a, size_t n )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    for ( ; i < n; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    printf( "\n" );
}


void alloc_new( int **a, size_t n )
{
    int *tmp = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) );

    if ( tmp )
    {
        free( *a );
        *a = tmp;
    }   
}

int main(void)
{
    int *a;
    size_t n = 4;

    a = calloc( n, sizeof( int ) );

    init( &a, n, 0 );
    display( a, n );

    alloc_new( &a, n );

    init( &a, n, 10 );
    display( a, n );

    free( a );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, my solution doesn't have a memory leak either, it just allocates the memory inside the function instead of outside.

Comment: @reshad What do you mean?

Comment: @reshad these are both correct solutions. Instead of accusing us of being wrong, you should show how you are (likely incorrectly) printing the array in ``main``.

Comment: oh ! sorry ! I am not accusing you. I am really thankful for your help but it does not work. :(

Comment: in the main i am printing it with : for(i=0; i<4; i++) printf("%d", array[i]);

Comment: @reshad A appended my post one more.:)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should *declare* `function` before you use it in main.    The compiler may produce the wrong code if it thinks that `function` expects an `int` argument when it should be an `int**` argument...

Did you just add a declaration, or did i miss it?  If so, sorry!

Comment: He probably just omitted that from his code block, like a few other things he told us after-the-fact.

Comment: I already did that, but I did not write it here, to be brief.